# DND number checking API

Tags: api, phone-number

I need to check if a mobile number is **registered** or not in the **Do Not Disturb (DND)** registry from my asp.net web application.
Is there **API** to check whether a mobile number is registered or not?

Comment: Can you conform that the you're referring to the **Indian DND registry** so that there can be more clarity?

Answer (score 2):

Try Free DND check http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999
It give you JSON output
I found it at http://checkdnd.com

Comment: I liked this API, it supports worldwide mobile numbers, I have tested many Indian numbers and few UK, USA numbers, must say it gave me 100% correct results (so far), still I am in dilemma to use it on my production application, anyone used it on their app ? if yes, did it stand on your expectations ?

Comment: I have tried 7-8 mobile numbers. It gave wrong information in 50% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a number is registered for DND using an api at https://www.mashape.com/blaazetech/dnd-check . You need to register to get an api key. But it is free.

There is also another API that doesn't require registration. It can be found at http://dndchecker.railsroot.com/

Answer (score -1):

While it is not free, there is the Data 24-7 service, which does have an API. Here is the link to their site:

[Data 24-7 website](http://www.data24-7.com/)